# Move files starting with number and of type pdf

Tags: regex, linux

I am just a beginner in `regex`, so please forgive me if this question is too easy.
What I want to ask is that I have a bunch of `files` in a directory and I move some of the files which start with `numbers` and of type `pdf`. How to use regex with `mv` command and what would be the `regex`.

Comment: That's quite simple. Why don't you try reading up on [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info) basics?

Comment: I have used mv [0-9]*pdf destination_folder, but its not working

Comment: ^ leads to front, \d is a number, $ denotes last, \. is a dot, . is any character. Rest rests on you dear!

Comment: If you're using linux command prompt, actually you're not using Regex, but you're using GLOB notation instead, which is different. Read up on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using linux command prompt, actually you're not using [Regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info), but you're using [GLOB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) notation instead, which is different. Read up on that. GLOB cannot take complex pattern such as the one you describe. You need to use real regex.

For your case, you can use `grep` command on the output of `ls` to find the files meeting your requirement, then call `mv` on them. Something like this:

```
while read fileName; do mv $fileName destination_folder; done < <(ls -1 | grep -E '[0-9].*\.pdf')
```

Let's break it up:

```
while read fileName; do
    mv $fileName destination_folder;
done < <(ls -1 | grep -E '[0-9].*\.pdf')
```

So basically you read through the directory listing using `while` loop, which gets the input from the output of the last line `ls -1 | grep -E '[0-9].*\.pdf'`. Using `while` loop (instead of simpler `for` loop) is necessary to cater filenames containing spaces.

Now the command `ls -1 | grep -E '[0-9].*\.pdf'` basically just list down the filenames, and grab only those matching specified RegEx pattern.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `find` too:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "[0-9]*.pdf" -exec mv {} destination \;
```